# Amanda Backup between restricted networks [server and client not in same network]

Tags: ssh, backup, amanda

We are planning to use Zmanda/Amanda community backup in our organisation.
The problem we are facing is that we have our servers scattered at different data centers across globe, some are in client network, so we don't have seamless access to the servers.

We have only ssh connection to the clients, and after reading thru documentations and forum, i understand that amanda uses a port range and 10080 port to take backup, which is not possible in this case.

Our network topology is something like this:
[image: Image-click-Here]

Can someone suggest how can we achieve configuring amanda in this scenario.
if I've missed something...

Comment: Why not use ssh tunnels or perhaps OpenVPN?

Comment: VPN, ssh tunnels, IPv6...

Comment: thanks guys, i can try ssh tunnels, but for VPN its not possible.

Comment: Definitely get yourself some IPv6 as soon as you can. It eliminates this entire class of problem, reducing it to simply adding the right rules to the relevant firewalls.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ssh support built into AMANDA, assuming the binaries you have installed were built with that option enabled.  See the 'SSH COMMUNICATION AND AUTHENTICATION' section of man page amanda-auth for details.  As long as your AMANDA server and initiate SSH connections into the clients, that should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question regarding Amanda.

The default authentication method used by amanda is bsdtcp.
It is possible to change the default authentication to other available options such as bsd, krb5, rsh, ssh, ssl etc.

You can change the authentication type to ssh and use your ssh keys file to authenticate the communication between the server and the clients. This should work fine over VPN connections as well.

Refer the below link for more information on the authentication types and how to use them.

https://wiki.zmanda.com/man/amanda-auth.7.html

If you have any other questions, feel free to let us know.